# Insert watermark in Word Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, watermark

I am seeking a way to insert a watermark into Word documents. Here is the code I get by recording Macros,

```
Sub add_watermark()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect( _
        PowerPlusWaterMarkObject354239640, "PAID", "arial", 1, False, False, 0, 0 _
        ).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject354239640"
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextEffect.NormalizedHeight = False
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = False
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 315
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = CentimetersToPoints(9.31)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = CentimetersToPoints(13.96)
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapNone
    Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = 3
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
        wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = _
        wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    Selection.ShapeRange.Left = wdShapeCenter
    Selection.ShapeRange.Top = wdShapeCenter
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

But I have an "out of range" error after running the Macro in another document. When I debug it, this line
"Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject354239640" is highlighted.

Does anyone know how to tackle it?

Thanks,

Comment: Use a picture rather than a PP object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Sorry, I don't understand what you said. I am quite new to VBA. Could you elaborate on how to use a picture?

Comment: It is important that you realize that a watermark, in Word, is fundamentally a picture in a header. This concept is responsible for any problems you run into. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Troubleshooting_Watermarks -- See macropod's answer which (1) uses the Range rather than the Selection, and (2) adds a shape to the header range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something based on:

```
Sub AddPaidWatermark()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sWdth As Single, Shp As Shape
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
  With .PageSetup
    sWdth = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin - .Gutter
  End With     
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      If .Range.Characters.First.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        With .Range.Tables(1)
          .Rows.Add .Rows(1)
          .Split .Rows(2)
        End With
        .Range.Tables(1).Delete
        .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True
      End If
      Set Shp = .Shapes.AddTextEffect(msoTextEffect1, "PAID", "Arial", 1, False, False, 0, 0)
    End With
  With Shp
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
    .ZOrder msoBringToFront
    .Height = sWdth / 2 ^ 0.5
    .Width = .Height
    .Rotation = 315
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .Left = wdShapeCenter
    .Top = wdShapeCenter
    With .Fill
      .Visible = True
      .Solid
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    End With
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: good code. I am not familiar with ms word, so it was difficult to find a clear setting for the head part, which is good.

Comment: Hi macropod, thank you so much for your code. I tried your code and it works perfectly in a blank document. But it doesn't work when I want to insert a watermark in a document with an existing header. Should I modify your code to make it work? Sorry, I am new to ms VBA.

Comment: The presence of existing content in the header has no effect on the macro's workings. Regardless of what's already there, the 'PAID' watermark gets inserted. The only situation in which the inserted 'PAID' watermark might not be visible is if there's another shape in the header occupying the same physical area as that in which the 'PAID' watermark is displayed; in that case, it's possible the 'PAID' watermark will end up behind the other shape. I've added a line to the code to address that possibility (i.e., 
 .ZOrder msoBringToFront).

Comment: Hi macropad. Sorry to reply to you so late. I still have problems adding the trademark. Currently, there is a table in the header. Would the table be occupying the same area where the 'PAID' watermark is displayed?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you told us from the outset how your document is structured. If the header starts with the table, that will indeed affect the positioning of the watermark, but not its presence. Code updated to account for that.

Comment: Hi Macropod. Your updated code works! Thank you so much.